# Elasticsearch-dsl with nested filters and AND and OR conditions with exact match

Tags: python, python-3.x, elasticsearch, flask, elasticsearch-dsl

Three parameters come from the front-end:

1. `State` - string
2. `Categories` - an array of strings. String can consist of several words.
3. `Tags` - similar to categories.

All parameters are optional.

*If several are transmitted*, need to implement their bundle through `AND` (and the coincidence of the `state`, and `category`, and `tag`). *If multiple `categories` or `tags` are submitted*, a match is made for at *least one of them*.

That is, if a **request arrives with the parameters**

```
{"state": "Alaska", "categories": ["category 1", "category 2"]}
```

**answers will be**

- `state = Alaska`, `categories = category 1`;
- `state = Alaska, categories = category 2`;
- `state = Alaska, categories = [category 1, category 2]`;
- `state = Alaska, categories = [category 1, category 3]` (*has at least one of the requested categories*).

**do not fit**

- `state = Alabama, categories = category 1`
- `state = Alaska, categories = 3`
- `state = Alaska, categories = 1 category` (*category name should be 1-in-1* `"category 1" != "1 category"`)

To `elastikserch` I send requests from a `python` (3.7). Took a library
[elasticsearch-dsl](https://elasticsearch-dsl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Collected *three filters* through `Q` objects (used `match` in them).

```
combined_filter = state_filter & categories_filter & tags_filter
```

*Lists of `categories` and `tags`* are divided into `subfilters through OR`.

```
query = queries.pop()
for item in queries:
    query |= item
```

Such a request is created for `elasticsearch`.

```
Bool(minimum_should_match=1, 
    must=[Match(state='Alaska'), MatchAll()], 
    should=[Match(categories='category 1'), Match(categories='category 2')]
)
```

Why this logic find entries by **not exact** `category` / `tag` names?

```
from typing import List

from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
from elasticsearch_dsl import Q, Search
from flask import request
from flask.views import MethodView


es = Elasticsearch()


class ArticleSearchAPIView(MethodView):
    """
    Search articles using ElasticSearch
    """

    @staticmethod
    def filter_create(queries: List[Q]) -> Q:
        """
        Creates Q.OR filter
        """
        query = queries.pop()
        for item in queries:
            query |= item
        return query

    def get(self) -> dict:
        """
        Search article
        First request - with empty params
        """
        search = Search(using=es, index=ArticleModel.__tablename__)
        state_filter = categories_filter = tags_filter = Q()
        result = "Articles not found."

        data = request.get_json()
        categories = data.get("categories")
        tags = data.get("tags")
        state = data.get("state")

        if state:
            state_filter = Q("match", state=state)

        if categories:
            queries = [Q("match", categories=value) for value in categories]
            categories_filter = self.filter_create(queries)

        if tags:
            queries = [Q("match", tags=value) for value in tags]
            tags_filter = self.filter_create(queries)

        combined_filter = state_filter & categories_filter & tags_filter
        found = (
            search.filter(combined_filter)
            .execute()
            .to_dict()["hits"]
            .get("hits")
        )

        if found:
            result = [article["_source"] for article in found]
        return {"response": result}
```

**Update**

---

Relationship between `Article and Category` and `Article and Tag` - `MTM`

Mapping

```
{
  "articles": {
    "mappings": {
      "properties": {
        ...
        "categories": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "ignore_above": 256
            }
          }
        },
        "state": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "ignore_above": 256
            }
          }
        },
        "tags": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "ignore_above": 256
            }
          }
        }
        ...
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided that using `elasticsearch-dsl` is unnecessary here.

Here is what decision I came to.

```
from typing import Dict, List, Tuple, Union

from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
from flask import request
from flask.views import MethodView

from .models import AticleModel  # ArticleModel.__tablename__ == "articles"


es = Elasticsearch()


class ArticleSearchAPIView(MethodView):
    """
    Search articles using ElasticSearch
    """

    def get(
        self,
    ) -> Union[
        Dict[str, Union[list, List[str]]],
        Tuple[Dict[str, str], int],
        Dict[str, Union[list, str]],
    ]:
        """
        Search articles
        """
        data = request.get_json()
        categories = data.get("categories")
        tags = data.get("tags")
        state = data.get("state")
        result = "Articles not found."

        query = {"bool": {"must": []}}
        if state:
            query["bool"]["must"].append({"term": {"state.keyword": state}})
        if categories:
            query["bool"]["must"].append(
                {"terms": {"categories.keyword": categories}}
            )
        if tags:
            query["bool"]["must"].append({"terms": {"tags.keyword": tags}})

        found = es.search(
            index=ArticleModel.__tablename__, body={"query": query},
        )["hits"].get("hits")

        if found:
            result = [article["_source"] for article in found]
        return {"response": result}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Boolean Query.

In bool query [ElasticSearch Boolean Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html)

You have 'must' which is equivalent to 'AND' operator. And 'should' which acts as 'OR' operator.

```html
{
  "query": {
    "bool" : {
      "must" : {
        "term" : { "user" : "kimchy" }
      },
      "should" : [
        { "term" : { "tag" : "wow" } },
        { "term" : { "tag" : "elasticsearch" } }
      ],
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank. But I don't understand, how can to run this query from my code?(

Comment: Not sure about the component you're using. But usually theres an option to run raw query as well..so you can format raw elasticsearch query like above and if your component allows, you can just pass this raw query and any other required parameters to the component and you can get similar results that you'll get after using the abstraction layer.

Comment: I try it later.

Comment: This does not work. Perhaps because `Article and Category`, `Article and Tag` have an `MTM` relationship?
Also, I tried to run `query` only with `state`. But the result is 0. `es.search(index='articles', body={"query": {"term": {"state": "Alabama"}}})`

Comment: whats your index mapping?